# Mapping over collections and returning the same type of container as the input

Tags: scala, generics, higher-kinded-types

For learning purposes, I am trying to define a wrapper class called `DoubleMap` which provides the method `mapBoth`. It essentially takes two functions `f` and `g`, where the domain of `g` is the co-domain of `f`. The composition of this function (*g o f*) should then be mapped of the container wrapped by `DoubleMap`

This is my current code:

```
implicit class DoubleMap
[A, B, C, F[X] <: List[X]] // just List for now
(xs: F[A])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[F[A], C, F[C]]) {
  def mapBoth(f: A => B)(g: B => C): F[C] =
    xs.map(f andThen g).to[F]
}
```

However, when I want to use the method like this:

```
List(true, false, false).mapBoth(!_)(!_)
```

I get a cryptical error message about the type mismatch between the (found) type `CanBuildFrom[List[_], Nothing, List[Nothing]]` and the (required) type `CanBuildFrom[List[Boolean], C, List[C]]`

Why does the compiler infer the first type?

Comment: **Scala** `2.12` or `2.13`? -  _(I assume `2.12` for the **CanBuildFrom**)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes. I read that this was renamed in 2.13 and that those generic methods now don't return a collection of the type they were invoked on anymore. Do I recall that correctly?

Comment: in `2.13` the collections framework was reworked and heavily simplified, for example this kind of tasks are now _"easier"_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Feel free to supply an answer for Scala 2.13!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call expands to

```
DoubleMap(xs).mapBoth(!_)(!_)
```

so all of `DoubleMap`'s type parameters and `cbf` need to be inferred *before* the `mapBoth` call is handled. To fix it, just move these parameters to `mapBoth`:

```
implicit class DoubleMap
[A, F[X] <: List[X]] // just List for now
(xs: F[A]) {
  def mapBoth[B, C](f: A => B)(g: B => C)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[F[A], C, F[C]]): F[C] =
    xs.map(f andThen g).to[F]
}
```

Then `B` and `C` are determined from `f` and `g`, and `cbf` from `F`, `A` and `C`.

Comment: That makes so much sense it almost hurts. I didn't know that implicit classes were expanded like this. When writing it out like this with explicit type parameters it also compiles fine and it's clear why inference fails! Thank you.

Comment: A little complement to show how to cover any kind of collection as well as best practices with **implicit classes** [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ERFfylpMS6SiATMQ197h2g/6)

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to not be tied to `List`, consider `Functor` from Cats

```
implicit class DoubleMap[F[_]: Functor, A](xs: F[A]) {
  def mapBoth[B, C](f: A => B)(g: B => C): F[C] =
    xs.map(f andThen g)
}
```

or vanilla Scala 2.13 approach (inspired by Luis' 2.12 [implementation](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ERFfylpMS6SiATMQ197h2g/6))

```
implicit class DoubleMap[F[x] <: IterableOnce[x], A](xs: F[A]) {
  def mapBoth[B, C](f: A => B)(g: B => C)(implicit bf: BuildFrom[F[A], C, F[C]]): F[C] =
    bf.fromSpecific(xs)(xs.iterator.map(f andThen g))
}
```

which both output

```
List(true, false, false).mapBoth(!_)(!_)
Vector(true, false, false).mapBoth(!_)(!_)

res1: List[Boolean] = List(true, false, false)
res2: Vector[Boolean] = Vector(true, false, false)
```

Comment: Yes that seems right. I really have never bothered too much with transforming any kind of collection, I usually use an specific collection or **Functor** :p

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am writing about Scala's type system in my bachelor thesis which is why I didn't want to use APIs outside the standard library. The 2.13 version looks good though!